# FuelPHP Assets in subfolders

Tags: fuelphp

Is it possible to use Assets to include files that are in sub folders?

Example:
[base_url] /assets/css/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.css

Answer (score 3):

You can access subfolders of the asset/ folder with this:

```
// Image in /assets/img1.jpg
print Asset::img("img1.png"); 

// Image in /assets/subfolder/img2.jpg
print Asset::img("subfolder/img2.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2):

In `./fuel/core/config/asset.php`, you can alter the following code:

```
/**
 * An array of paths that will be searched for assets. Each asset is a
 * RELATIVE path from the base_url WITH a trailing slash:
 *
 * array('assets/')
 */
'paths' => array(''),
```

And

```
/**
 * Asset Sub-folders
 *
 * Names for the img, js and css folders (inside the asset path).
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 * img/
 * js/
 * css/
 *
 * This MUST include the trailing slash ('/')
 */
'img_dir' => 'img/',
'js_dir' => 'js/',
'css_dir' => 'css/'
```

If you configure `paths` to be `assets` and `css_dir` to be `css/`, you can include `[base_url] /assets/css/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.css` by using `echo Asset::css('pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.css');`

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you just set the paths in asset.php to whatever you like:

```
$config['asset_paths'] = array('assets/');
```

That is if you want to use the Asset library. Otherwise just make them absolute paths from webroot.